# Function object is not subscritable in python

Tags: function, python-3.x, object, coordinates

I am trying to do a really simple code which generates random coordinates on a board. To do that I defined a board function, then I randomly generate a coordinate on one row and one column.

The program works fine for the row but I can't manage to make it generate a random column. (I am coding in python just in case)

[image]

Could someone help me, please ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, put the code as text in your question (and format it as code using Ctrl/Cmd+K).

Comment: ... and don't use the same name for functions and variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generates one random row and one random column:

```
import random

def board():
    board = []
    for x in range(0, 5):
        board.append(["0"] * 5)
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
    return board

def random_row(board):
    rr = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
    return rr

def random_col(board):
    rc = random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
    return rc

theboard = board()
# generate random row and column
rndrow = random_row(theboard)
rndcol = random_col(theboard)

print(rndrow)
print(rndcol)
```